# Implmentation of an erfinvl() function in pure ANSI C

Tags: library, math, c

While studying density function of normal distribution I got the need to create a program for my embedded device which can find [image: a] in those kind of Gaussian Probability density *(for example)* : [image] or in [image] with [image: normal distribution parameters].

The problem is creating an inverse error function is currently beyond my mathematical knowledge.
So is there a long double version implementation of an inverse error function?

Update I forgot to say I have access to the standard MS-DOS 5.0 API as I am using a CPU which is binary compatible with the 80286. It mean I have the`long double`variants of the standard functions which are part of`math.h`*(`powl()` `expl()` `srqtl()` `strtoul()`…)*

Comment: Does your CPU have floating point hardware (287)?

Comment: @Gilles : No, but the compiler provide an option to emulate an x87. I'm not getting `Domain error` error messages when the option is enabled. So it doesn't fully matter. However the point I'm using a compatible 80286 does matter since it means I can't run code which is designed for POSIX. Things like djgpp require the 80386 instruction set.